# (knex/mysql) how to update an extremely large table by chunks?

Tags: mysql, knex.js

I am using knex, with my sql,

I have several large databases with several tables in each database, and some of the tables reach 10 million rows, some more and some less,

I want to update a specific column values in each table (lets call it `value`), with a function that doesn't exist in mySQL, (it only exists in my code) and I understand that I need to do it in batches, like take each time 1,000 or 5,000 or 200,000 rows and change the `value` for the entire array, and then use an upSert query to update the rows with the new values.

but how many rows should I fetch (`SELECT`) each time I'm taking the data from the database?

how much rows should I update (`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`) each time I want to update the new calculated `values` in the table?

efficiency, and bug handling are key factors here,
should I increase the ram size of the db? the cpu? can I even?

I've searched in the mySQL documentation and didn't find anything on it,

I'd love any help with the matter

Comment: note that INSERT..ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE has the drawback of actually inserting if for some reason you specify a unique key that doesn't exist.  consider using a table value constructor instead; see https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9b320de7516ac3cac1b787c4d314049 (unioned select where 0 is just to give the columns names - VALUES gives default names, but they differ between mysql and mariadb)

Comment: also, doing multiple updates makes more sense when just updating a portion of the rows; if you are updating all rows, you may do better creating a new table with ids and new values (batching inserts to it) and doing a single update that joins that

Comment: I echo Rick James; at 100 to 1000 you are going to get practically all the benefit possible from just batching.  try it out, and only if it is still unacceptable start looking at database capacity/tuning

Comment: @ysth thanks but I'm using MySQL 5.7 so it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

**Batches of between 100 and 1000.**  For similar situations, this range is the "sweet spot".  Without knowing your specifics, I believe that this range will work well for you.  I predict it will be within a "few percent" of optimal.

- For less than 100, you will be paying more overhead because of having more roundtrips to the server.
- For more than 1000, you will be in "diminishing returns" and threatening to hit limits (such as the ones mentioned).  And for a variety or reasons (locking, undo log processing, etc), going much beyond 1000 may actually degrade performance.

**Beware:** `SELECT ... OFFSET ...` gets slower and slower; do not use that technique.  Instead, "remember where you left off".  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks (The discussion there can be adapted to Updates and Upserts (IODKU).)

**_size settings:**

The main tunable [assuming the tables are InnoDB, which you *should* be using] is **`innodb_buffer_pool_size`**, which should be set to about 70% of *available* RAM.  If your entire disk footprint (for all the tables) is less than the buffer_pool, then increasing the setting further (after first adding more RAM), is not useful.  Again, "diminishing returns" may kick in.  That is, at some point more RAM is not worth adding.  (This point is very dependent on far more details than can be discussed here.)

**`join_buffer_size`** is relevant only for certain `SELECTs`.  Let's see your `SELECT`, plus `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Meanwhile, the other "size" settings can probably be left at their default settings.  (Some, such as **table_cache_size**, are irrelevant to the task.)

How many **cores/CPUs** -- Mostly not an issue.

Will you be trying to run **multiple threads (connections)** simultaneously?  If so, elaborate; this gets into a different set of issues.

**How many queries of what size** -- "It depends".  I could fabricate a short Select on a small table that would take days to run.  At the other extreme, I say that you can do 100 *per second* "simple queries" on virtually any MySQL installation.  "Simple implies a good index, with very few rows involved.  Writing (Insert/Update/Delete) more than 100/second on HDD (or 1000 on SSD) *may* get difficult.  That is, you may need to use some techniques that are not obvious to the novice.

Now, let's look at the **root of your question** "each time I want to update the new calculated values in the table?".  There are several "better" ways to achieve the same goal:

- Put the data in another, smaller, table and JOIN to it.
- "generated" (virtual or persistent) column.
- Do the computations in the `SELECTs`.

My point here is that a "big Update" is usually not the best way to design the schema and dataflow.

"I've searched in the MySQL **documentation** and didn't find anything on it,"  Yeah, a "reference manual" is designed to say what you *can do*, not what you *should do*.  My blogs (such as the one linked above) try to focus on the latter.

"10 million rows" -- Your questions get more exciting at "1 billion rows".